# Dell does not power down when long-pressing power button?

Tags: power, poweroff, dell

I have a Dell Precision 7770. I performed a UEFI (BIOS) update. It hasn't done anything since then. In the [Technical Guidebook](https://www.delltechnologies.com/asset/en-us/products/workstations/technical-support/precision-7770-technical-guidebook.pdf) it says,

> Power button with optional finger print reader
>
> - Press to turn on the computer if it is turned off, in sleep state, or in hibernate state.
> - Press to put the computer in sleep state if it is turned on.
> - Press and hold for four seconds to force shut-down the computer.
> - Press and hold for 25 seconds to force Real Time Clock (RTC) battery reset.

Yet, when I press the power button for four seconds it doesn't go off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dell power delivery system is no longer controlled by the power button, it's instead wired as an interrupt. The [official advice from Dell Cares](https://www.dell.com/community/en/conversations/inspiron-desktops/desktop-froze-updating-firmware-do-not-power-off/647f9763f4ccf8a8dea571db) is,

> If the BIOS update stalls for longer than 1 hour, try to power the Laptop off. If still no go,
>
> - disconnect the power adapter,
> - **remove the base cover,**
> - **disconnect the battery cable from the motherboard.**
> - Wait 5 minutes.
> - Reconnect the battery cable to the motherboard,
> - then reconnect the power adapter to the Laptop and try to power on.

Yea, I know. But, dude you got a Dell,

[image: Dell face]